# Integrating Spring-Hibernate Using HibernateTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I required to integrate hibernate with spring and have to use HibernateTemplate for performing database operation.
But its throwing below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:235)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession(HibernateTemplate.java:470)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:405)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:694)
at com.shubham.SpringHibernateAssignment.StudentDAO.saveStudent(StudentDAO.java:19)
at com.shubham.SpringHibernateAssignment.App.main(App.java:26)
```

find below code for **StudentDAO.java** class which uses HibernateTemplate for performing DB operations.

```
public class StudentDAO   {
     HibernateTemplate template;  
      public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
          this.template = template;  
    }

    public void saveStudent(Student stud){


    template.save(stud);
    }

    public Student getById(int id){  
           Student e=(Student)template.get(Student.class,id);  
           return e;  
    }  

    public List<Student> listAll(){  
        List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();  
        list=template.loadAll(Student.class);  
        return list;  
    }  

}
```

**Here is the Configuration file - applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false"></property>
        <property name="username" value="hbstudent"></property>
        <property name="password" value="hbstudent"></property>
     </bean>

<bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>student.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="com.shubham.SpringHibernateAssignment.StudentDAO">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

Comment: Going to need more than this. How are yo wiring hibernate into spring and establishing the configuration. Also hibernate is up to version 5 now. Might want to update. Check out http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring

Comment: Where is the code? of StudentDAO?